# I have two tables (Temp1 & finalTemp)

Tags: sql

I have two tables (Temp1 & finalTemp)

**temp1**

```
AccId  Name  address city GuarantorId
1       abc   xyz     a       11
1       qwe   asd     a       115
2        kk    aa     t        21
3       t       u      p       96
```

now I want my finalTemp like

```
AccId  Name1  address1 city1  Name2  address2 city2 Name3  address3 city3
 1     abc     xyz      a     qwe      asd      a     null   null    null
 2     kk       aa      t      null    null     null  null    null   null
3       t        u       p
```

Comment: Did you have a question in there?

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Self `LEFT JOIN`?

```
select t1.*,t2.*
from temp t1
  left join temp t2 on t1.AccId = t2.AccId and t1.name < t2.name
```

Or, extended, double self left join:

```
select t1.*,t2.*,t3.*
from temp t1
  left join temp t2 on t1.AccId = t2.AccId and t1.name < t2.name
  left join temp t3 on t2.AccId = t3.AccId and t2.name < t3.name
```

Comment: the op says he has 2 tables. anyways there is ambiguity in the question

Comment: @vkp, I've noticed. Maybe OP counts the result table as well?